# How can I write a trigger in SQL Server with CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the problem: I want the user to enter the value "d%" in the "Status" column, the value is "done", and if "p%" is entered, the value "processing" is set.

Example code:

```
create trigger Update_status
on orders 
after insert, UPDATE
as
    update orders
       case orders.status like
          when 'd%' then set orders.status='done'
          when 'p%' then set orders.status='processing'
       end
```

Comment: Aside: Your trigger doesn't reference the `inserted` or `deleted` tables, it always updates _all_ rows in `orders`. It is also a best practice to contemplate a `default` clause for a `case` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire `case` statement needs to be the value you set the field to.

```
create trigger Update_status
on orders 
after insert, UPDATE
as
    update orders
    set order.status = 
       case
           when orders.status like 'd%' then 'done'
           when orders.status like 'p%' then 'processing'
       end
```

Comment: OMG! But I was close! :))) Thanks for the prompt help!

Comment: But still....you need to reference inserted and/or deleted. As coded here this will update every row in the entire table when any row is inserted or updated.

Comment: Definitely true.  A better answer would use an INSTEAD OF trigger with the method you described.  Also, this behavior probably shouldn't be in a trigger in the first place anyway.